# Are changes to closed over variables visible in callbacks using the closure?

Tags: javascript

If I have an array that is in a closure and that closure has been passed as a callback, will changes to the array be visible in the callback?

E.g.

```
function ctor ( func ) {
  this.func = func;
}

ctor.prototype.do = function() {
  this.func();
}

var arr = [];

function doSomethingWithArr() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i ) {
    console.log( arr[i] );
  }
}

var a = new ctor( doSomethingWithArr );

a.do(); // should print nothing

arr.push( "Hello" );
arr.push( "World" );

a.do(); 
// expect:
// "Hello"
// "World"
```

The reason I asked the question was because after trying this and it not working, even after fixing my typing mistake: `console.log(i)` -> `console.log( arr[i] )`, and searching on here for similar questions I found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will changes to the array be visible in the callback?

Yes, a closure does maintain a *reference* to the closed-over variables, it does not create copies of the values (which in case of an array would still be an object reference anyway).

Comment: Thanks. I guess there is something else that is wrong then. The above example doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @Hector: Hm, since you edited to `arr[i]` it does log exactly what is expected when I copy your code verbatim into the console